# Vim keep cursor location while scrolling

Tags: vim

Is there a way to keep the cusror location off-screen in Vim / gVim while scrolling?  Similar to many Windows editors.
I know about marks, and do use them.  I also know the '.' mark (last edit location), But looking for other ideas.
I'm asking this because sometimes i want to keep the cursor at some location, scroll to another place using the mouse-wheel, and then just press an arow key or something to get me back to that location.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No. vim is a console application, so it doesn't really make sense to have the cursour off-screen (it's possible, but would just be confusing)

An alternative solution, to paraphrase posts from [this thread from comp.editors](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.editors/browse_thread/thread/2ed904497fe930fa):

`Ctrl+o` goes to the previous cursor location, `Ctrl+i` goes to the next (like undo/redo for motions)

Marks seem like the other solution..

> Also, use marks. Marks are named by letters. For instance typing  ma remembers
>   the current location under mark a. To jump to the line containing mark a,
>   type 'a. To the exact location use `a.
>
> Lower-case-letter marks are per-file. Upper-case-letter marks are global;
>   `A will switch to the file containing mark A, to the exact location.

Basically `ma`, move around, then `a to jump back.

Another option which Paul suggested,

> `gi` command switches Vim to Insert mode and places cursor in the same position as where Insert mode was stopped last time.

Comment: "vim is a console application" - yeh gVim/MacVim are GUI applications, but they are ports/extensions to the console vim, and can't really change too much

Comment: Should also add in Paul's response below.

Comment: By "it's possible" do you mean it can be implemented in your vimrc somehow, or would you have to modify vim's source?

Comment: @trusktr I meant it's technically possible (e.g [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649733/hide-cursor-on-remote-terminal)).. I guess you could maybe write a vim script to have offscreen cursors (e.g vim-multicursor creates fake cursors - maybe it's possible to hide them, faking an offscreen cursor?)

Comment: @truskt Any progress? I'd use this quite a bit, I think. I'm really not a fan of the philosophy that because gVim came out of Vim, it should remain faithful in silly ways to the terminal world.

Comment: @KyleStrand Not yet actually, but check out the NeoVim project on github. It's been discussed to add this feature there.

Comment: I do keep meaning to check that out, but it'll have to wait until I have some spare time to spend trying to get it built on Windows. I'm pretty excited for it, though, because I think it's pretty likely to eventually replace gVim as my editor.

Answer (score 20):

Why don't you split the window, look at what you wanted to look at, and then close the split?

```
:split
```

or

```
:vsplit (if you want to split vertically)
```

Comment: ... which can be abbreviated to :sp and :vs

Comment: I'm actually more used to using Ctrl+W,S and Ctrl+W,V rather than the commands...

Answer (score 19):

The only similar behavior that I've found in Vim:

<kbd>z</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> or <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd> "scroll the screen down as far as possible without moving the cursor"

<kbd>z</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> "scroll as far up as possible".

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> "scroll one line down, if possible"

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>"scroll one line up, if possible"

Comment: while this answer doesn't match the question body, it is the exact match for the question title, which is what I need. Thank you.
I'd like to add this: `z-Enter` is the same as `z-t`

Answer (score 12):

Sometimes you can avoid jumping to marks before entering text — `gi` command switches Vim to Insert mode and places cursor in the same position as where Insert mode was stopped last time.

Comment: I didn't know about this one but it reminded me of another that I use, among the variety of ways of doing this given here: you can make a line edit, and then undo it, then go look around, and then just redo/undo the edit again and the redo flips you back to where the edit was. It's like a mark I guess but you don't have to remember a letter. I also bind `U` to redo so the undo/redo is really quick: `uU`.

Answer (score 4):

Google says that the cursor (and therefore current line) must be visible in Vi, so you'll have to use marks.

Comment: i thought so too, but just wanted to make sure from fellow vimmers.

Comment: Anything is possible with programming. :D

Answer (score 4):

Also very useful are the '' (2x single quotes) and `` (2x back quotes).
The former jumps back to the line you were prior to the last jump (for instance, a page down).
The latter jumps back to the line *and* column you were prior to the last jump.